# All rspec tests passing when they should not (Rails 3.2, Rspec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

I'm building a daily deal rails app and I have followed M. Hartl tutorial to set some rspec tests.

For users they work perfectly.

But now I have used it for the model Eals and all are passing, when they shouldn't. For example, in my models, I put that titles can't be longer than 200 characters (note:on my  view, when I try to set titles longer than this, it works and alerts me it's not possible)

But when I do tests no matter if I try for the title character length's test with long = "a" * 50, a * 201 or even a * 10000 in the title test, it always pass! There is a big problem I don't manage to find.
And actually all the other tests have the same problem: they always pass!

Here is my models/deal.rb

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :admin_user

 attr_accessible :url_path, 
                 :country, 
                 :title,
                 :description,
                 :twitter_msg,
                 :admin_user_id

 validates :url_path,
          presence: true,
          uniqueness: { :case_sensitive => false }
 validates :country, 
          :inclusion => {  :in => ['France', 'Germany', 'United States'],
                           :message => "%{value} is not a valid country. " }
 validates :title,
          presence: true,
          length: { maximum: 200, 
                    :message => "Your title has %{value} characters but must be shorter than 200 characters" }  
validates :description,
          presence: true,
          length: { maximum: 500,
                    :message => "Your title has %{value} characters but must be shorter than 500 characters" } 
validates :twitter_msg,
         presence: true,
         uniqueness: { :case_sensitive => false }


validates :admin_user_id, presence: true
```

And my deal_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Deal do

let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

before (:each) do
    @attr = {       url_path: "lorem ipsum",
                    country:"France",                        
                    title:  "lorem ipsum", 
                    description:"lorem ipsum",
                    twitter_msg:"lorem ipsum",
                                     }
end

it { should respond_to(:url_path) }
it { should respond_to(:country) }
it { should respond_to(:title) }
it { should respond_to(:description) }
it { should respond_to(:twitter_msg) }

describe "title test" do

it "should reject deals with title that is too long" do
  long = "a" * 50
  hash = @attr.merge(:title => long)
  Deal.new(hash).should_not be_valid
end

[other tests] 

 end #end of title test
```

If anybody can help me understand that, that would be great, I have been spending hours without any clue.

After following sb advice, I changed my test with

```
Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:title)

    describe "test" do

    it "should reject games with title that is too long" do
      long = "a" * 250
      hash = @attr.merge(:title => long)
      Game.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:title)
    end
    end
```

But now it's passing all the time, i.e it's telling me I have one error on title no matter if I put long= "a" * 5, long="a" * 300...

Comment: Did you try `long = "a" * 201` instead of `long = "a" * 200`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev i tried to put a * 200, a* 50 (inferior to 200), a * 500 (superior to 200)...they all pass. It's like my test aren't really done and it says pass all the time

Comment: Fire up `rails c`, and make a new `Deal` object with these attributes and inspect it.  For whatever reason, you're not getting what you expected, it's much easier to play w/the object directly and find out.

Comment: Try to fill right values into all fields that have `presence: true`.

Comment: Is the test database empty? Perhaps there are already rows in the database that conflict the `uniqueness` validators.

Comment: Re your update - the validation in models is not just for the view.  It will be applied anytime you try to create or update a model, through the controller, console, migration - whatever.  In `rails c`, type `deal = Deal.new` then `deal.valid?`.  If that returns false the validation is working.  `deal.errors` will show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [shoulda_matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) for testing such things

Answer (score 4):

This is not the correct way to test validation using RSpec because it doesn't tell you why the object is invalid. It may be invalid because you're missing a totally different attribute that the one you're testing for. You should be using the `have(x).errors_on(y)` assertion:

```
Deal.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:title)
```

Comment: this is quite true, never thought of that (i 'm a newbie in RoR). I'll definitely use your syntax, it's great but is keeps passing whatever value i put ( a* 5, a* 200, a* 4000), it keeps passing! Tobe precise it keeps telling me i have 1 error in all cases!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try the following code? It should give you a hint what attribute is invalid (and why):

```
it "..." do
  d = Deal.new(@attr)
  d.valid?
  puts d.errors.full_messages
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`admin_user_id` is not in your `@attr` hash.  However it's mandatory on your `Deal` model - so your test always passes because the new deal is not valid.  Nothing to do with the length of the title.

Comment: i  have put it but nothing seems to change